# linux: socket programming, accept(sd, null, null)

Tags: linux, sockets

I have a question about socket programming.

The prototype of the accept () function is as follows:

```
int accept(int s, struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t *addrlen);
```

What I want to know is what happens when I put null in the second and third arguments?

```
accept(sd, NULL, NULL);
```

Can it run normally without information about `sockaddr`? If so, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [`accept`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/accept.2.html) returns, the `addr` and `addrlen` parameters are used to fill in information about the source (*ie*, peer). By passing in `NULL` for `addr`, `addrlen` is ignored, and no information is returned. You don't actually need to know who the peer is to begin a network transaction, but having is helpful for logging or access control. If you don't get the peer information on `accept`, but you need it later, you would have to call [`getpeername`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpeername.2.html).

Comment: Thanks for your kindness. This is very helpful to me.